# How can I remove only one attribute value and not another with jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, dynamic, attributes

So I have found all over stackoverflow how to remove an entire attribute, however I only want to remove the first value of an onClick attribute but not the second. All my different instances of each container have a unique function associated to them and they all share the first function in common... Once any of these containers are clicked, the first function needs to be gone but I need to retain the second without altering it at all. My code follows:

```
<div class="halves marginal" onClick="buildFrame(),viscalc()">
<div class="two_one marginal" onClick="buildFrame(),percentOf()">
```

etc etc

Once buildFrame() executes once:

```
function buildFrame(){
document.getElementById('screenframe').innerHTML = "<img src='img/screen.png'><iframe id='framecontent'>";
```

I would like to remove it from each class ( but keep percentOf(), viscalc() etc etc )

How can I remove only one attribute value and not the other?

Comment: the onclick attribute only has one value. There is only one value to remove. If you want to remove part of it, you'll have to modify it using string manipulation.

Comment: Ah thats it! So get attribute value and remove string "buildFrame()"?

Comment: Another option would be to modify the `buildFrame()` function to check if its already been run. Something like `var frameBuilt = false;function buildFrame(){if(!frameBuilt){[code] frameBuilt = true;}}`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

so this is what i would do.

```
$("div.marginal").on("click", function(){
   $(this).off("click", buildFrame);
});
```

that removes it from the event queue for the functions listener.

You cant do it with anon functions.

idea:

```
$("div.marginal").on("click", function(){ 
    var funcs = $(this).attr("onclick").split(",");
    $(this).attr("onclick", funcs[1]);
    console.log("value of 'onclick'", $(this).attr("onclick"));

    // or alternatively

    $(this).off("click", funcs[0].substr(0,funcs[0].length-2))
    //this breaks apart the onclick, turns off the click event for event0, while maintaining
    //   the second event.
});
```

the issue that i can see, from my point of view is that since it is inline, it really executes it once, so changing onclicks value might not be enough as it might not be refreshed.  The above jquery though, will do what your case would want.

Comment: this will look for the buildFrame function inside the click queue for that object, and then remove it.  I honestly forget if it removes all instances, or just the first encountered.  I am fairly certain it will remove all occurrences of the function call on event.

Comment: I don't think this will work for the handlers within the onclick attribute.

Comment: I try to keep JS out of markup so that users can easy swap out UIs.  Let me see if i can do it with a fiddle.

Comment: Cant seem to get it working for some reason.  My example keeps thinking the functions are undefined for some reason.  *shrug*  No fiddle this time. :(

Comment: I agree, it's just that, this can't possibly answer the question without also showing how to replace all of those onclick attributes with the jquery way of doing it.

Comment: It didn't seem to have any effect... Does it matter that the function is written in standard JavaScript? If I rewrite using jQuery will this work?

Comment: it would, though, sadly does not solve the problem the way you liked, as KevinB said, but just does it a different way.   I like to write all the markup, and then list all manipulatable controls in JS vs ID reference, and assign stuff there.  Its clean and allows you to swap out huge chunks of markup without breaking stuff, or change what a control actually does by replacing its js component.

Answer (score 0):

I think the most pin-pointed approach to this would be pass this in your buildFrame and then inside the buildFrame remove itself from the calling object.

```
<div class="halves marginal" onClick="buildFrame(this),viscalc()">


function buildFrame(obj){
    document.getElementById('screenframe').innerHTML = "<img src='img/screen.png'><iframe id='framecontent'>";
    // not sure why your not closing the iframe tag ill assume you wanted it this way
    $( this ).off("click", buildFrame);
};
```

** EDIT **

Missed your edit where you want to remove it from all instances, this complicates it much, this solution is no longer viable.

Answer (score 0):

Fairly straightforward to do with a custom selector. I think this can be done without the eval() but I'm not sure how offhand.

Here you go:

**HTML**

```
<div class="halves marginal" onClick="buildFrame();viscalc();"></div>
<div class="two_one marginal" onClick="buildFrame();percentOf();"></div>
```

**Javascript**

```
$.expr[':'].hasFrameMethod = function(obj){
  var onClick = $(obj).attr('onClick');  
  return onClick != undefined ? onClick.split(';').indexOf("buildFrame()") != -1 : false;   
};

function buildFrame(){
    document.getElementById('screenframe').innerHTML = "<img src='img/screen.png'><iframe id='framecontent'>";      

    $('div:hasFrameMethod').each(function(idx, item){
        htItem = $(item);
        var itemClickFns = htItem.attr('onClick') != undefined ? htItem.attr('onClick').split(';') : (htItem.attr('onclick') != undefined ? htItem.attr('onclick').split(';') : "");
        htItem.attr('onClick', '');
        htItem.attr('onclick', '');
        htItem.off("click");

        // re-add any correct secondary actions
        if(itemClickFns.length > 1){

            var strFnClick = "function onclick(event) { ";

            itemClickFns.forEach(function(elem,idx){
                if(elem != "buildFrame()"){
                    if(elem.length > 0){
                        strFnClick += elem + ";";
                        htItem.attr('onclick', htItem.attr('onclick') + elem + ";");
                    }
                }                               
            });

            strFnClick += "}";

            // Rebind the event
            htItem.prop('onclick', eval(strFnClick));
            htItem.click(eval(strFnClick));
        }
    });
}
```

As long as this code loads after jQuery it should work. :)